# How to set parameter values for stored procedure activity in ADF pipeline because there is no values in system variables

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, audit-logging

First I have created an `audit_log` table structure in Azure SQL database. After that, I have created copy activity and one stored procedure. I want, when I run this pipeline, to store the pipeline activity details into `audit_log` table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

actually got this to work with dynamic number of parameters, not "just" a single parameter with a different name. The trick was to pass into the activity a json string (or construct it in the activity) that looks like...

```
{"Params":{"ParameterName1":{"value":"ParameterName1Value","type":"String"}}} for one parameter
{"Params":{"ParameterName1":{"value":"ParameterName1Value","type":"String"}, "ParameterName2":{"value":"ParameterName2Value","type":"Int"}}} for two
```

then in the Copy Activity Source Side I have:

```
@json(string(pipeline().parameters.SourceProcParameters)).Params
```

in the "Stored Procedure Parameters" add dynamic content.

(full disclosure, I only have run it with proc with one parameter, but I'm fairly confident it will work with multiple parameters!)

And I think the same will work for Exec Procedure activity

Comment: Can confirm that this did, indeed, work with an arbitrary amount of stored procedure parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can add system variables in the `stored procedure` activity.

Edit the parameter value and click on the **Add dynamic content**. It will pop a window, where you can select the required system variables from the list to add the content dynamically.

[image]

[image]